# How to copy images in DIST folder from assets in Vite js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I use Vite with reactjs. I heavily rely on the assets folder to render data and display images.

After I build the website page, I seen that the images folder is not coppied into the assets.

Update:

```
eyecam-co.svg:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "image/svg+xml". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
the-air-filter-company.svg:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "image/svg+xml". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
index-DR3CgUjj.js:40 Error loading image: TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:3000/jobfilters/assets/images/photosnap.svg
index-DR3CgUjj.js:40 Error loading image: TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:3000/jobfilters/assets/images/manage.svg
(anonymous) @   index-DR3CgUjj.js:40
```

How I render then images. I needed to point dynamically to the image folder.

```
const CardWrapper = ({ company, setConditions }) => {
    
    const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState(null);
    /**
     *      Load Images dynamically
    //  *          
    */
    useEffect(() => {
        const loadImage = async () => {
            try {
                const dynamicImage = await
                import(/* @vite-ignore */ `../../assets/images/${company.logo}`);

                setImageSrc(dynamicImage.default);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error loading image:', error);
            }
        };

        loadImage();
    }, [company.logo]);
```

Than, I setup the assets thatI want to include into the vite build:

```
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: '/jobfilters/',
  build: {assetsInclude: ['src/assets/**']},
  plugins: [react()]  
})
```

https://github.com/ddmihai/jobfilters
https://ddmihai.github.io/jobfilters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to take into account:

- First, the `assetsInclude` is not meant to use like you did, but to specify some special formats that by default are not included by vite when you import them.
- Regarding your problem, you should ask yourself if you need to treat the companies logos as dynamic assets that they can change from time to time and you need to hash them every time you build the project for that reason. If that is not the case, I would recommend you to put these images in the public directory as the companies logos won't be needed to be loaded dynamically nor probably be changed very often so they can be cached, something like this:

```
public /
  images/
    company.svg
    other-company.svg
```

Then reference them directly

```
<img src={`/jobfilters/images/${company.logo}`} alt='company svg' width={70} height={70} />
```

So you won't need to manage the imageSrc in a `useEffect` to set the image based on the company logo.

- If you still want to import the images like an asset (using import), I think the problem is caused by the `@vite-ignore` as I guess (not sure) is forcing vite build to ignore the import and thus generating the asset. If you remove the comment, it is warning you that you must include the extension to import a file dynamically, so to allow working it correctly, remove the extension of `.svg` of each company.logo in your data file at `src/assets/data/data.json` and add it manually in the import image like:

```
await import(`../../assets/images/${company.logo}.svg`);
```

The docs of vite about [static asset handling](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets#the-public-directory) talks about when you would need to use public, when you would need to use the `assetsInclude` and other important aspects to know about.